# How to use wildcard in a string in php?

Tags: php

I am using PHP to access some folders with a specific path starting with the letter: "C".
Can I somehow use a wild character in order to get all the folders names starting with C?

For example I have three folders as: Camera, Center, Calls
The sub directories of these paths are the same.
How can I do something like this in PHP:

```
$var = "C*/folder_1/folder2/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`glob()`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.glob.php) function.

```
var_dump(glob('C*/folder_1/folder2/'));
```